# An inequality in Erdős–Rényi random graph model

Tags: probability, random-graphs

Let's consider Erdős–Rényi random graph model. This means that the probability assigned to a graph $G_{n,p}$ with $n$ vertexes and $m$ edges is equal to
$$P(G_{n, p}) = p^{m}(1-p)^{N-m},$$
where $N = {n\choose 2}$.

I am to prove that
$$P(G_{n, p_1} \in \mathcal{P}) \le P(G_{n, p_2} \in \mathcal{P}) \tag{1}$$
for $0 \le p_1 \le p_2 \le 1$ and any graph property $\mathcal{P}$.

I'm a bit confused because let's assume that $n=4, m=2, p_1=0.1, p_2=0.9$. Then $P(G_{n, p_1})=  0.006561$ and $P(G_{n, p_2}) = 0.000081$. What do I not understand? I would appreciate to get a sketch of a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a note on $P(G_{n,p})=p^m(1-p)^{N-m}$ : This is the probability that your random graph return a *specific graph* $H$ on $m$ edges. So intuitively if $H$ has very few edges ($m\ll N$), then it's more probable to get this specific graph if you chose a small $p$.

Now, the statement

$$P(G_{n, p_1} \in \mathcal{P}) \le P(G_{n, p_2} \in \mathcal{P}) $$
does **not** hold for  **any** graph property $\mathcal{P}$ and any $0 \le p_1 \le p_2 \le 1$

For instance, let $\mathcal{P}$ be the property of being disconnected, or having diameter at least 2, and take the extreme case $p_2=1$, then
$$P(G_{n, p_2} \in \mathcal{P})=0$$
while for any $0<p_1<1$, $P(G_{n, p_1} \in \mathcal{P})>0$

In general note that by defining $\mathcal{Q}$ as the negation of $\mathcal{P}$,
$$P(G_{n, p} \in \mathcal{P}) +P(G_{n, p} \in \mathcal{Q}) = 1$$
Therefore if
$$P(G_{n, p_1} \in \mathcal{P}) < P(G_{n, p_2} \in \mathcal{P}) $$
Then
$$1-P(G_{n, p_1} \in \mathcal{Q}) < 1-P(G_{n, p_2} \in \mathcal{Q}) $$
$$P(G_{n, p_1} \in \mathcal{Q}) > P(G_{n, p_2} \in \mathcal{Q}) $$